# Dynamically Add Rows in Google Visualization API (JavaScript)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-visualization

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 project that requires me to upload a.xls / .xlsx by user input, load it into a DataTable and place a visual of it in the view.

Sounds easy enough...

I am able to create the DataTable and pass the object back to the view, however I am unable to render the data table on the view via Google's visualization API -- all of the examples I have seen require statically denoted fields, i.e.:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
data.addRows([
  ['Work', 11],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['Commute', 2],
  ['Watch TV', 2],
  ['Sleep', {v:7, f:'7.000'}]
]);
```

However, since my application is taking user input, the column headers, dimensions, and content are all dynamic. I am looking for a way to add the data dynamically. Here is the code I currently have, where Model is the DataTable being passed in:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using GridMvc.Html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "File Upload";
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
}

<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
        function drawTable( Model ) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var numRows = Model.Rows.Count;
            var numCols = Model.Rows[0].Count;

            for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
                data.addColumn('string', Model.Rows[0].ItemArray[i]);

            for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++)
                data.addRow(Model.Rows[i].ItemArray);         

            //data.addRows([['2967773', '13-1014428', '', 'Not Recommended -Internship', '7- Not Recommended',
            //                'University 1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ]]);

            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
            table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='table_div'></div>
  </body>
  <p>Done</p>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, the ASP.net `DataTable` is not the same thing as the Google Visualization API `DataTable`.  If you want to use the ASP.net DataTable, you need to parse its contents into a Visualization API DataTable.  You might want to look into creating a compatible object server-side and outputting it as a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment above mentions, `DataTables` from C# are not the same as `DataTables` in the Google API.  I ended up finding a third party library ([Example](https://gist.github.com/johnw86/2820853)) that handled this and just passed the following into viewbag:

```
ViewBag.Data = new Bortosky.Google.Visualization.GoogleDataTable(ConvertTable( DATA )).GetJson();
```